# Unknown model type bjt - ignored

Tags: ngspice

I am trying to use Transistor model as in the NGSpice manual `8.2 BJT Models (NPN/PNP)`:

```
.model QMOD1 BJT level=2
```

however, I got this error:

```
  q1 n15 n16 n17 qmod1
could not find a valid modelname
Warning: Model issue on line 61 :
  .model qmod1 bjt level=2.end ...
Unknown model type bjt - ignored
```

So, why I got `Unknown model type bjt` ?

Comment: Are the files which contain the model (model files), included in the netlist?

Comment: Yes, its, kindly see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell what type it is (NPN or PNP) if it is defined like `.model QMOD1 BJT level=2`.

You need to substitue BJT by NPN or PNP. So, `.model QMOD1 PNP level=2`

Check also [SPICE BJT Declaration](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/168555/Modeling_BJTs_in_Multisim.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Huisman for enlightening me